# Partitioning an Oracle table by schema

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to partition a table in Oracle by schema?

The specific example I'm wanting to use is to create a public tablespace called "billing" that contains a master transaction table that has all of the elements common to a transaction (trans id, date, transaction completed, etc) but also has an additional column for an "application id" that stores which web application created the transaction.

In other words, I would like to have several different web applications with their own schemas to reference the same public transactions table, but be filtered by the "application id" and only let them be able to see transactions created by that web application.

For example, say we have two web applications that have their own tablespaces (tablespace_1 and tablespace_2) and they can both see the public "billing.transactions" table, but each tablespace can only see those transactions relative to their schema, i.e. tablespace_1 can only see transactions that have an "application id" of 1, and tablespace_2 can only see transactions with an "application id" of 2.

Is this even possible?

For the record, I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: You can do this with views. The app can be given SELECT permission on the view even if it doesn't have permission on the underlying table.

Comment: I thought about that, but the drawback to that is I would have to create a view for each tablespace that I would have to update if I ever altered the underlying transactions table. After doing some research I stumbled on to the solution that I believe will work. It's called "Virtual Private Database". This lets me dynamically control which app sees which data and doesn't require maintaining separate views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after doing a bit of googling I managed to come up with the solution that I wanted. It's called "Virtual Private Database".

This lets me auto-append an application ID to a query by schema user and enforces integrity by schema user so that they can only insert/update/select the transactions they should be able to see.